# Libreoffice command line HTML to PDF conversion: images are skipped

Tags: html, pdf, libreoffice

I am using the following command to generate PDF from a simple HTML file:

```
soffice.exe --infilter="HTML Document" --headless --norestore --writer --convert-to pdf input.html
```

HTML file looks like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black;}
.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black;}
.tg .tg-cly1{text-align:left;vertical-align:middle}
</style>
<table class="tg" width="900" border="1" align="center" valign="top">
<tr>
<th class="tg-cly1"><b>some text</b><br></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tg-cly1"><font color="red">SOME MORE TEXT</font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tg-cly1"><img src="c:/foo/bar\baz\image2.jpg" alt="image2"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tg-cly1"><font color="green">AND MORE TEXT</font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tg-cly1"><img src="c:/foo/bar\baz\image2.jpg" alt="image2"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tg-cly1"><font color="yellow">SOME MORE</font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tg-cly1"><img src="c:/foo/bar\baz\image3.jpg" alt="image3"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The resulting PDF is missing the images. Everything else renders fine. What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE: I got this to work by replacing `c:/foo/bar\baz\...` with `file:///c:/foo/bar/baz/...`. Without this LibreOffice was not displaying the images resoling their path to `file:///<MY CURRENT DIR>/c:/foo/bar\baz\...`. Can I make changes to LibreOffice so that I DON'T need to modify the HTMLs?

Comment: Are the images accessible from the running LibreOffice?

Comment: @thebusybee are you asking whether "c:/foo/bar\baz\image1/2/3.jpg" actually exist? Yes, they do. I can convert these HTMLs to PDFs from command line using chrome but I prefer to use `soffice` instead

Comment: @thebusybee see UPDATE above

Comment: Well, your HTML should be well-written up-front. I would use relative paths, and only forward-slashes.

Comment: Hi, I Z Have you thought about HTML validation ?  https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea